# Load set of images - Matlab-->C++ translation

Tags: c++, matlab, fits

I have a Matlab script that I'm trying to convert to C++ (see below) because it is extremely slow. I'm a C++ newbie and to start I tried using `codegen` but it doesn't work (I got the message *??? This text contains non-empty top-level expressions.  It appears to be a script.*)

Do you have any suggestion on how to start to convert the code? Also, what is the best C++ function to do the job of `fitsread`?

Here is my code:

```
clear;

number_projections = 10;
imgs_per_proj = 2000; % Number of images per projection

% Lets load the reference images relative to the various wavelengths

R1 = zeros(imgs_per_proj, 512, 512);
R2 = zeros(imgs_per_proj, 512, 512);

l = 0;
for k = 1:imgs_per_proj
    s = sprintf('Ref/R1_000_%05i.fits',k-1);
    t = sprintf('Ref/R2_000_%05i.fits',k-1);
    l = l + 1;
    R1(l,:,:) = fitsread(s);
    R2(l,:,:) = fitsread(t);
end
```

Comment: This MATLAB snippit is almost certainly I/O bound rather than compute bound.  Translating to C++ is unlikely to make any difference in runtime.

Comment: Before trying to rewrite it in C++, a language with which you're unfamiliar, you might try to look into what performance measurements you can make using matlab narrow down exactly where the slowness is coming from.  As @Peter mentioned it's unlikely that you'd see much benefit since nothing about this is CPU-bound.  How much memory does the machine have that you're running this on?  It looks like you're simultaneously building up two 2000x512x512 images in memory.  If the values in those images are 64-bit floats that's nearly 8 GB.  A lot of the slowness could just be page thrashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`codegen` requires that the MATLAB code you're trying to convert be in a function and it seems you are trying to convert a script

However,  even if you do that, `fitsread` does not appear to be a supported function within `codegen`. Here's a list of supported functions:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html

There's no "built-in" function within C++ that's going to replace `fitsread` - for that you need a library. There's a C++ FITS library called `CCFits` that you can find here: http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/

They should have tutorials that you could follow.